# Code to protect workbook ignores exceptions and range

Tags: excel, vba

I have created some VBA code using snippets online with the aim of locking down a worksheet so that the header column cannot be edited, nor any rows or columns being inserted or deleted. However the main data needs to be editable and for ease of use by the end user, filtering and sorting needs to be possible. However, the code just creates a completely locked workbook- no editing, sorting, or filtering is possible.

```
    Rows(1).Locked = True
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Psswrd"
    ActiveSheet.Protect Contents:=False
    AllowInsertingColumns = False
    AllowInsertingRows = False
    AllowSorting = True
    AllowFiltering = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fails for me on the first command already because of wrong syntax.

The parameters for the ActiveSheet.Protect command should not be placed on different rows as separate commands They need to be parameters of the main command.

If you need help with the syntax, you can start the macro recorder, protect the sheet, tick all the boxes, then stop the macro recorder. That will give you the syntax for the options you want, except for the password. You will find that the parameters are all in one statement, and you can add the password parameter like

```
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, _
    AllowInsertingColumns:=True, AllowInsertingRows:=True, AllowFiltering:= True, _
    Password:="Psswrd"
```

Unless you specify a parameter as `True`, it will default to `False`, so you only need to list the items that you want to be TRUE.

Also, by default, all cells are locked. You need to explicitly unlock the cells that you want to keep editable after the sheet is protected.